# Why aren't my h elements displaying block?

Tags: css, overflow

I'm having an annoying problem where my h elements (h2 for example) are floating after the previous elements.

I thought that h elements should just display block, aka, start on a new line? I guess I'm wrong. Also, am I wrong about what display: block means? I thought it meant that that div will take up all the space from left to right, which I thought would mean that it should start on a new line and when it's over with, the next element will also display on a new line.

I tried putting clear: both; and overflow: hidden; in the css of my h elements but it's not working.

The page looks like a mess with everything floating after each other, (right now just pictures and h2s). When I inspect the h2 elements in chrome (I'm viewing all this in chrome), the blue part, the actual element, is going all the way across, but my text isn't. The text is starting after the previous element.

I would like all of my h elements to always be on their own line, filling from left to right.

[a screen shot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEW6j.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your HTML and CSS codes?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Notice that the image on the left is floating to the left side (`float: left`) which means that the text on the right will surround the image. Try to add `clear: both` to your `h2` and `overflow: auto` to your image or its container.

Comment: THanks! This solved it. Next time I'll try to include the code, I was just hoping someone new a quick solution and @SebastianMuszyński did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not only add the `clear: both`, but also `overflow: auto` to the container/parent element of the floating elements, so that it takes all the space the floating elements take.